# How to build pcl in_hand_scanner

Tags: ros, pcl, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04. The PCL I use is pcl17 downloaded and compiled from source(refer to [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl17) page). The compilation finished without errors.

I'm trying to learn recognition, and I found the 3D pointcloud model that is to be recognized in the scene is usually required. And then I found [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/in_hand_scanner.php#in-hand-scanner), the in-hand-scanner in the tutorial documentation, that seems to help me build my own 3D pointcloud model for recognition.

However, I tried to find it in this folder:

```
~/pcl_overlay/install_isolated/bin
```

and there is no executable file which has the name related to in-hand-scanner. The folder is not empty. There are several executable files that looks related to the applications in this folder:

```
~/pcl_overlay/src/pcl_unstable/pcl/pcl_trunk/src/apps
```

There is a folder named in_hand_scanner in the apps folder, too.

I found some discussion on the Internet and set -DBUILD_apps=ON in the CMakeLists.txt of the package, and then compile it again. After compilation there are more executable files appear in the bin folder such as pcl_openni_tracking, but still, there is no pcl_in_hand_scanner.

What should I do to generate the in-hand-scanner executable file, or is there a better way to build a 3D pointcloud model? Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67253/how-to-build-pcl-in_hand_scanner/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2013-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might have to enable the other flag BUILD_app_in_hand_scanner. When you run CMake, you should see a summary of the apps that it will build (usually saying XXXapp is disabled).

---

Originally posted by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) with karma: 52 on 2013-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0